# Safari ignores CSS height

Tags: css, safari

Sorry but I don't know how to formulate this in a more general way...

On [this website](http://infimeunderwear.com/) there's an element with class `home-tryon-graphic`, which has a fixed height of 140px. In Chrome it displays well, but in Safari the height is disregarded and set to some other value.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `min-height: 100%` you should remove from the styles. It is applied to the:

`.home .banners .item-row > a > img`

If you can't edit that class, you can overwrite it by adding `min-height: 0px` to the `img.home-tryon-graphic` element